# React not re-rendering on state change

Tags: reactjs

I am rendering a new form when the button is clicked. So basically I change a state within the component from:

false to true or 
null to true

However, it is strange that component does not re-render after the state change

```
export default class BoardManager extends React.Component{
   constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      newForm : null
    };
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.state = {
        newForm : true
      };
      console.log(this.state.newForm);
    },1000);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        Some thing here
        {this.state.newForm ? <NewBoardForm />: null}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Help much appreciated!!!

Edit!!! Solution

```
export default class BoardManager extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      newForm : null
    };
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <BoardsTable boards={BoardData.boards}/>
        <button onClick={() => {
            this.setState({
              newForm : true
            });
            console.log(this.state.newForm);
          }}>Add New</button>
          <button onClick={() => {
              this.setState({
                newForm : null
              });
              console.log(this.state.newForm);
            }}>Delete</button>
        {this.state.newForm ? <NewBoardForm />: null}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Move the setTimeout call to inside a `componentDidMount` and use `this.setState` in there

Comment: @max_new it's good practice on Stack Overflow to accept (ie. "check") whichever answer actually answered your question.

Answer (score 8):

You have to use `this.setState({newForm: true})` instead of `this.state = {newForm : true}`

And put `setState` in [other lifecycle stages](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#lifecycle-methods).

Comment: I think in ES6 this.state is essentially this.setState

Comment: `this.state = ` is not the same as `this.setState`.

Comment: @max_new ES6 has nothing to do with these React-specific method calls

Comment: Thanks for comments guys. Appreciate it. In my experience, when I setState my render is getting called again while when I set this.state = {} the state is modified but render doesnt happen. I have read the lifecycle controllers and there is hook which is always set to true which causes render

Comment: Then you should probably be using `this.setState` and `shouldComponentUpdate`.

Comment: @Taysky and @David Hariri technically that's not 100% true.  In the `constructor` of an ES6 version of a React component (ie. `class MyComponent extends React.compont`) you *can* use `this.state =` instead of `this.setState`.  Not trying to confuse anyone, but I just wanted to mention that exception.

Comment: A few months ago that wasn't the case, but @machineghost is correct, you can now set the state using `this.state = {}` in the constructor. Don't use that way outside the constructor though.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this.forceUpdate() at the end of onClick.
Reference:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html